# extract weekdays from a set of dates in R

Tags: r, lubridate

I know using the `lubridate` package, I can generate the respective weekday for each date of entry. I am now dealing with a large dataset having a lot of date entries and I wish to extract weekdays for each date entries. I think it is quite impossible to search for each date and to find weekdays. I will love to have a function that will allow me to insert my date column from my data frame and will produce days corresponding to each dates of the frame.

my frame is like

```
uinq_id Product_ID Date_of_order count
1 Aarkios04_2014-09-09  Aarkios04    2014-09-09    10
2    ABEE01_2014-08-18     ABEE01    2014-08-18     1
3    ABEE01_2014-08-19     ABEE01    2014-08-19     0
4    ABEE01_2014-08-20     ABEE01    2014-08-20     0
5    ABEE01_2014-08-21     ABEE01    2014-08-21     0
6    ABEE01_2014-08-22     ABEE01    2014-08-22     0
```

i am trying to generate

```
uinq_id Product_ID Date_of_order count                      weekday   
1 Aarkios04_2014-09-09  Aarkios04    2014-09-09    10       Tues
2    ABEE01_2014-08-18     ABEE01    2014-08-18     1       Mon  
3    ABEE01_2014-08-19     ABEE01    2014-08-19     0       Tues   
4    ABEE01_2014-08-20     ABEE01    2014-08-20     0       Wed 
5    ABEE01_2014-08-21     ABEE01    2014-08-21     0       Thurs
6    ABEE01_2014-08-22     ABEE01    2014-08-22     0       Fri
```

any help will be highly beneficial.
thank you.

Answer (score 14):

Using `weekdays` from base R you can do this for a vector all at once:

```
temp = data.frame(timestamp = Sys.Date() + 1:20)
> head(temp)
   timestamp
1 2016-06-01
2 2016-06-02
3 2016-06-03
4 2016-06-04
5 2016-06-05
6 2016-06-06
temp$weekday = weekdays(temp$timestamp)
> head(temp)
   timestamp   weekday
1 2016-06-01 Wednesday
2 2016-06-02  Thursday
3 2016-06-03    Friday
4 2016-06-04  Saturday
5 2016-06-05    Sunday
6 2016-06-06    Monday
```

Comment: Watch out: the output of weekdays depends on the locale of the system that you're running this on!

Answer (score 5):

We can use `format` to get the output

```
df1$weekday <- format(as.Date(df1$Date_of_order), "%a")
df1$weekday
#[1] "Tue" "Mon" "Tue" "Wed" "Thu" "Fri"
```

According to `?strptime`

> %a - Abbreviated weekday name in the current locale on this platform.
>   (Also matches full name on input: in some locales there are no
>   abbreviations of names.)

Comment: it worked fine. i am a fresher in R. can you please tell me what does "%a" imply?

Comment: @HindolGanguly  According to `?strptime` `%a - Abbreviated weekday name in the current locale on this platform. (Also matches full name on input: in some locales there are no abbreviations of names.)`

Comment: ok that's great. can i also find week-number and month name using the same package? what should i use then instead of "%a"?

Comment: @HindolGanguly  These are base R functions.  You don't need to load any package.  For monthname, use `%b` and weekday `%u`

Answer (score 5):

```
library(lubridate)

date <- as.Date(yourdata$Date_of_order, format = "%Y/%m/%d")
   
yourdata$WeekDay <- weekdays(date)
```